# groupby and agg by multiple columns error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group by `monthtly_purchases` and `region` to get the count of customers and sum of monthly spending, however, I get the error below:

Main dataframe:

```
customer_id   monthly_spending      month             monthtly_purchases       region     
32324         342                   Feb-2019          5                        A
34345         293                   Feb-2019          5                        A
45453         212                   Feb-2019          3                        A
34343         453                   Feb-2019          3                        A
53533         112                   Feb-2019          5                        B
12334         511                   Feb-2019          5                        B
99934         123                   Feb-2019          3                        B
21213         534                   Feb-2019          3                        B
32324         143                   March-2019        5                        A
34345         453                   March-2019        5                        A
45453         234                   March-2019        3                        A
34343         432                   March-2019        3                        A
53533         124                   March-2019        5                        B
12334         453                   March-2019        5                        B
99934         224                   March-2019        3                        B
21213         634                   March-2019        3                        B
```

Output dataframe:

```
monthly_purchases region    monthly_spending    count_customers         month
5                 A         635               2                       Feb-2019
3                 A         665               2                       Feb-2019
5                 B         623               2                       Feb-2019
3                 B         657               2                       Feb-2019

5                 A         596               2                       Feb-2019
3                 A         666               2                       Feb-2019
5                 B         556               2                       Feb-2019
3                 B         858               2                       Feb-2019
```

This is what I've tried so far but I get the following error:

```
d = {'customer_id': ['count'], 'monthly_spending': ['sum']}

agg_df = df.groupby('monthtly_purchases', 'region').agg(d)
agg_df

Error msg: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Comment: `total_spending` is not a column in the original df

Comment: apologies it should be 'monthly_spending' not 'total_spending'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to put the column names inside a list, when you use group by over 2 or more columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
[32324, 342, "Feb-2019", 5, "A"],
[34345, 293, "Feb-2019", 5, "A"],
[45453, 212, "Feb-2019", 3, "A"],
[34343, 453, "Feb-2019", 3, "A"],
[53533, 112, "Feb-2019", 5, "B"],
[12334, 511, "Feb-2019", 5, "B"],
[99934, 123, "Feb-2019", 3, "B"],
[21213, 534, "Feb-2019", 3, "B"]
],
columns=["customer_id", "monthly_spending", "month", "monthtly_purchases", "region"]
)

d = {'customer_id': ['count'], 'monthly_spending': ['sum']}
agg_df = df.groupby(["monthtly_purchases", "region"]).agg(d)
print(agg_df)
```

Returns:

```
                          customer_id monthly_spending
                                count              sum
monthtly_purchases region                             
3                  A                2              665
                   B                2              657
5                  A                2              635
                   B                2              623
```

As requested in the comments, making the multi-index explicit (splitting it into columns by creating a new index):

```
agg_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(agg_df)
```

Returns:

```
  monthtly_purchases region customer_id monthly_spending
                                  count              sum
0                  3      A           2              665
1                  3      B           2              657
2                  5      A           2              635
3                  5      B           2              623
```

Including months as requested in the comments:

```
agg_df = df.groupby(["month", "monthtly_purchases", "region"], as_index=False).agg(d)
```

Returns:

```
        month monthtly_purchases region customer_id monthly_spending
                                              count              sum
0    Feb-2019                  3      A           2              665
1    Feb-2019                  3      B           2              657
2    Feb-2019                  5      A           2              635
3    Feb-2019                  5      B           2              623
4  March-2019                  3      A           2              666
5  March-2019                  3      B           2              858
6  March-2019                  5      A           2              596
7  March-2019                  5      B           2              577
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. But how can I show the `monthly_purchases` value on each row. I.e. showing `monthly_purchases` = 3 not only in the first row but also second row

Comment: It already exists, just implicit as part of the new `agg_df` DataFrame MultiIndex .You can verify this by the following: `print(agg_df.index)`

Comment: when I add the `month_column` to the groupby I get instead of `customer_id` count = 2 only 1

Comment: Grouping by the column `month` is the same as not grouping at all, since this column only has a single value (`Feb-2019`) repeated. The answer has been updated wrt. your enquiry on the Multi-Index

Comment: I have edited my question. Assumption is that there are multiple months. So for each  `month`,`region` and `monthly_purchases`: **sum** `monthly_spending` and **count**  `customer_id`

Comment: The answer has been updated to include the additional column `month` in the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the columns is different, but you can get it with the following code.

```
df = df.groupby(['monthtly_purchases','region','month']).agg({'customer_id': 'size', 'monthly_spending': 'sum'}).reset_index()
df
    monthtly_purchases  region  month   customer_id monthly_spending
0   3   A   Feb-2019    2   665
1   3   B   Feb-2019    2   657
2   5   A   Feb-2019    2   635
3   5   B   Feb-2019    2   623
```